# Even generating function with Stirling numbers of the second kind

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, stirling-numbers

Is there a known closed form for the following generating function?
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{S(n, k)}{(2n) !}x^{2n}y^k
$$
If we had $n!$ at the denominator instead, this would simply be the well-known mixed generating function $e^{y(e^{x^2}-1)}$, but the $(2n)!$ changes everything. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Indeed, that was a typo! Thanks!

Comment: The fundamental reason for the usual generate function, with $2n$ replaced by $n,$ is that $$\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}\frac{S(n,k)}{n!}x^n = \frac{(e^x-1)^k}{k!}.$$ I don't see any obvious way to replace $n!$ with $(2n)!$ there. Is there a reason you think there should be a closed formula? There often isn't one. Essentially, you are seeking the exponential generating function for $\frac{n!S(n,k)}{(2n)!}.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yeah I'm aware of the usual g.f. The one I am looking for is relevant to a problem in random graph theory, which is why I posted this question. I indeed do not have a specific reason to believe there is a closed formula, but I figured I had nothing to lose trying.

Comment: Funny but perhaps not useful $e^{-y}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\cosh(x\sqrt{n})y^n/n!$